# Proper way to upgrade kernel in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel

My current kernel is very old (2.6.32-042stab120.16), and I want to upgrade it to a more recent version. I have issued the following commands to install the new kernel:

```
apt-get update
apt-cache search linux-image
apt-get install linux-image-4.10.0-14-generic
```

But after a reboot, it still show the old kernel

```
root@servername:~# uname -a
Linux servername 2.6.32-042stab120.16 #1 SMP Tue Dec 13 20:58:28 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So I'd like to ask what is the standard way to upgrade kernel?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You are using a VPS. You can't upgrade kernels there.

Comment: Have you upgraded your system several times from older versions? Ubuntu 10.04 LTS --> 12.04 LTS --> 14.04 LTS --> 16.04 LTS? Did you prevent using a newer kernel version some time long ago? Is there some output, when you run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.10.0-14-generic` ? Is it an option to install a fresh 16.04.1 Ubuntu Server system?

Comment: Oh, is it? I remember in the past I had some issue with an old kernel with high load in 12.04 or 14.04 VPS (can't remember exactly), then I upgraded and the issue was gone. Any way, will my vps provider be able to upgrade the kernel for me? Thanks!

Comment: No, that was a clean install of ubuntu 16.04 minimal for my VPS. It is serveing user's websites now, so I would want to try refraining from rebuld the system. The current problem of the system is it is running out of RAM but swap is very lightly used. Kernel starts killing process. The same websites on another provider runs without issues even with half of RAM. In the old provider swap used was 300MB consistently, but in the new provider it use only 1-4 MB swap, even though processes are being killed by kernel. So I wanted to upgrade kernel to see if there is any difference.